# How to apply my sed command to some lines of all my files?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I've 95 files that looks like :

```
2019-10-29-18-00/dev/xx;512.00;0.4;/var/x/xx/xxx
2019-10-29-18-00/dev/xx;512.00;0.68;/xx
2019-10-29-18-00/dev/xx;512.00;1.84;/xx/xx/xx
2019-10-29-18-00/dev/xx;512.00;80.08;/opt/xx/x
2019-10-29-18-00/dev/xx;20480.00;83.44;/var/x/x
2019-10-29-18-00/dev/xx;3584.00;840.43;/var/xx/x
2019-10-30-00-00/dev/xx;2048.00;411.59;/
2019-10-30-00-00/dev/xx;7168.00;6168.09;/usr
2019-10-30-00-00/dev/xx;3072.00;1036.1;/var
2019-10-30-00-00/dev/xx;5120.00;348.72;/tmp
2019-10-30-00-00/dev/xx;20480.00;2033.19;/home
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;5120.00;348.72;/tmp
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/hd1;20480.00;2037.62;/home
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;512.00;0.43;/xx
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;3584.00;794.39;/xx
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;512.00;0.4;/var/xx/xx/xx
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;512.00;0.68;/xx
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;512.00;1.84;/var/xx/xx
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;512.00;80.08;/opt/xx/x
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/xx;20480.00;83.44;/var/xx/xx
2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/x;3584.00;840.43;/var/xx/xx
```

For some lines I've `2019-10-29-18-00/dev` and for some other lines, I've `2019-10-30-12-00;/dev/`

I want to add the `;` before the `/dev/` where it is missing, so for that I use this sed command :

```
sed 's/\/dev/\;\/dev/'
```

But How I can apply this command for each lines where the `;` is missing ? I try this :

```
for i in $(cat /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/*.txt | grep -e "00/dev/")
do 
sed 's/\/dev/\;\/dev/' $i > $i
done
```

But it doesn't work... Can you help me ?

Comment: `... $i > $i` is dangerous. For tiny files it may work, but for larger files you'll probably end up with corrupt files. Use `sponge` to buffer the output or use the inline options of the commands you work with. (for instance, `sed` has the `-i`option)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following with GNU `awk`if you are ok with it.

```
awk -i inplace '/00\/dev\//{gsub(/00\/dev\//,"/00;/dev/")} 1'  *.txt
```

***`sed` solution:*** Tested with GNU `sed` for few files and it worked fine.

```
sed -i.bak  '/00\/dev/s/00\/dev/00\;\/dev/g' *.txt
```

Comment: Hello, I just want to add the `;` before the `/dev/`, I am not interested by the date

Comment: @Ezzmazz, Sure changed it now, lemme know in case of any queries please.

Comment: @Ezzmazz, I have added single `sed` solution too now, you need not to use for loop for it, I have tested it with few files in GNU sed and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel -q sed -i 's#;*/dev#;/dev#' ::: *.txt
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed -i 's#;*/dev#;/dev#' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` for filtering can be eliminated in your case, we can accomplish the task with a single `sed` command:

```
for f in $(cat /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/*.txt)
do 
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && sed -Ei '/00\/dev/ s/([^;])(\/dev)/\1;\2/' "$f"
done
```

Comment: Hello, When I try you loop, I've this error " sed: can't read 2019-10-28-18-00;/dev/XXXX;3584.00;2743.57;/var/opt/"

Comment: @Ezzmazz, that means there's no such file yet (for in-place edit). File under `$i` should exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore lines with `;/dev`.

```
sed '/;\/dev/{p;d}; s^/dev^;/dev^'
```

The `/;\/dev/` check if the line has `;/dev`. If it has `;/dev` do: `p` - print the current line and `d` - start from the beginning.

You can use any character with `s` command in `sed`. Also, there is no need in escaping `\;`, just `;`.

> How I can apply this command for each lines where the ; is missing ? I try this

Don't edit the same file redirecting to the same file `$i > $i`. Think about it. How can you re-write and read from the same file at the same time? You can't, the resulting file will be in most cases empty, as the `> $i` will "execute" first making the file empty, then `sed $i` will start running and it will read an empty file. Use a temporary file `sed ... "$i" > temp.txt; mv temp.txt "$i"` or use gnu extension `-i` `sed` option to edit in place.

What you want to do really is:

```
grep -l '00/dev/' /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/*.txt |
xargs -n1 sed -i '/;\/dev/{p;d}; s^/dev^;/dev^'
```

`grep -l` prints list of files that match the pattern, then `xargs` for each single one `-n1` of the files executes `sed` which `-i` edits files in place.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to adjust your regex so that it's looking a bit wider than '/dev/', e.g.

```
sed -i -E 's|([0-9])/dev|\1;/dev|'
```

(note that I'm taking advantage of sed's flexible approach to delimiters on substitute. Also, -E changes the group syntax)

Alternatively, sed lets you filter which lines it handles:

```
sed -i '/[0-9]\/dev/ s/\/dev/;/dev/'
```

This uses the same substitution you already have but only applied on lines that match the filter regex